# Can't play .wmv files after attempting to add DVD playback from medibuntu

Tags: vlc, medibuntu

i cannot see video with "movie player", "GNOME video" OR with "VLC media player" ... or in any browser .. ANnyone have any guesses??

Comment: Basically check if you have all the required restricted codecs installed. You can go with gstreamer or xine. Install gstreamer bad and ugly sets of codecs multiverse ones as well if you use gstreamer.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the 'w32codecs' package from Medibuntu.

Comment: And w64codecs if you have amd64 system.

Comment: You should also tell that it's probably illegal to do that...